# Unsupported request - method type: get

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Our app started getting the following error message on a very basic get that was working perfectly fine until recently

`https://graph.instagram.com/v12.0/me?access_token=<IG...>`

```json
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported request - method type: get",
      "type": "IGApiException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "A2KKkkTQ2nn70IQPCGKcKVB"
   }
}
```

What is this error? This has been working for months, and it looks like freshly created access_token do not have an issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting answer after days of research:

You need to get your business approved, and then this error will disappear.

The issue is that the dashboard was not letting us request a business approval since we did not use (supposedly) any API requiring such approval.

Long story short, you need to create another dummy app with the same business that needs business approval (e.g. a game). Ask for permission review, then once the permission review is pending, you will be able to require business approval. Once that's done, you can delete the dummy app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, going to try that and will update accordingly. Weird thing is that seems as this happens just sometimes, and not always.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, but it turned out to be caused by Facebook (confirmed by their employee). A few hours later, the Graph API returned to normal without any action taken.